# How to fill up masked area (globalCompositeOperation - destination out) in Javascript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have multiple canvases in my project.

**The first canvas** is just for performing a masked effect in the background.
[image]

**The second canvas** is where users see the real application. All actions, such as drawing and erasing, are performed on the second canvas.
[image]

For example, if I draw a mask on the second canvas using a paint tool, it will look like this:

[image]

---

And if I want to remove the masked part using an eraser, I am faced with this:

[image]

As you can see, the orange area is where I want to restore the masked area and I want to see the original image. (basically removing those masks on the orange area)

The entire code is too extensive to analyze here, so I've included only the part where I draw masks/erase.

```
if (event.target.name() === "baseImage") {
    isDrawingMask.value = true;

    if (konvaStage.value) {
      // Clear current line..
      currentLineMask.value = [];
      var pointerPosition = konvaStage.value.getNode().getPointerPosition();
      const scale = konvaStage.value.getNode().scale();
      const stagePosition = konvaStage.value.getNode().position();

      if (pointerPosition && scale) {
        const calculatedX = (pointerPosition.x - stagePosition.x) / scale.x;
        const calculatedY = (pointerPosition.y - stagePosition.y) / scale.y;

        currentLineMask.value = {
          stroke: "#df4b26",
          strokeWidth: 60,
          globalCompositeOperation:
            props.tool === "draw-mask" ? "destination-out" : "source-over",
          lineCap: "round",
          lineJoin: "round",
          points: [calculatedX, calculatedY, calculatedX, calculatedY],
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

The code may not look like typical canvas code because I use KonvaJS. However, the idea is the same.

So, I'm looking for a way to fill up that masked area back when using an eraser instead of drawing something. Do I need a third canvas or anything else to perform this operation? What are your thoughts?

Comment: What are you doing with this `currentLineMask` ?  ...  I think all you need is to subtract that from the masked area, where are you doing that?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda currentLineMask is just stores the data of line between current "mousedown", "mousemove" and "mouseup" events. When the user fires "mouseup" event, that data is pushed to "maskData" which is an array contains of "currentLineMask" data. So in the next cycle, when user fires "mousedown", the given code runs. Each line data is stored in order to perform actions such as "undo", "redo" etc. The maskData array is used to render lines on the canvas. I got the idea, I was trying to find sth about "globalCompositeOperation". I'll look it. Code: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/KJxp9QyGTW/